# parsing old xml to make a new one-document already has a root node c#

Tags: c#, xml, treeview, xmldocument

I have a XML file that is uploaded in a treeView and I have to make a new XML by treating old nodes as text and wrapping them with new tags and then saving it all into a file.I have to keep in mind which nodes are the child nodes and give them element tags.

```
        private void saveNode(TreeNode node, XmlNode xnode,XmlDocument xmlDoc1)
        {


            foreach (TreeNode tnode in treeView1.Nodes)
            {


                        xnode.AppendChild(xmlDoc1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, tnode.Text, tnode.Text));

                        XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc1.CreateElement("category");

                        XmlAttribute oid = rootNode.Attributes.Append(xmlDoc1.CreateAttribute("oid"));
                        oid.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        xmlDoc1.AppendChild(rootNode);

                        XmlElement dr = (XmlElement)rootNode.AppendChild(xmlDoc1.CreateElement("name"));
                        dr.AppendChild(xmlDoc1.CreateTextNode("Model"));
                        XmlElement com = (XmlElement)rootNode.AppendChild(xmlDoc1.CreateElement("comment"));
                        XmlElement condition = (XmlElement)rootNode.AppendChild(xmlDoc1.CreateElement("condition"));

                        xmlDoc1.AppendChild(rootNode);

                        saveNode(tnode, xnode,xmlDoc1);

                        if (node.NextNode != null)
                        {
                            foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes)
                            {

                                XmlNode root1 = xmlDoc1.CreateElement("elements");
                                root1.AppendChild(xmlDoc1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, tnode.Text, "elements"));
                                root1.InnerText = tnode.Text;
                                saveNode(tn, xnode, xmlDoc1);

                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes)
                            {
                                XmlNode root1 = xmlDoc1.CreateElement("elements");
                                root1.AppendChild(xmlDoc1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, tnode.Text, "elements"));
                                saveNode(tn, xnode, xmlDoc1);
                            }
                        }

               }

        }



        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            XmlDocument xmlDoc1 = new XmlDocument();


            XmlNode xroot = xmlDoc1.CreateElement("model");
            XmlAttribute oid = xroot.Attributes.Append(xmlDoc1.CreateAttribute("oid"));
            oid.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            xmlDoc1.AppendChild(xroot);

            XmlElement dr = (XmlElement)xroot.AppendChild(xmlDoc1.CreateElement("name"));
            dr.AppendChild(xmlDoc1.CreateTextNode("Model"));
            XmlElement com = (XmlElement)xroot.AppendChild(xmlDoc1.CreateElement("comment"));
            XmlElement condition = (XmlElement)xroot.AppendChild(xmlDoc1.CreateElement("condition"));
            XmlElement el = (XmlElement)xroot.AppendChild(xmlDoc1.CreateElement("element"));

            try
            {
                foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes)
                {
                    saveNode(tn, xroot,xmlDoc1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
            saveFileDialog1.AddExtension = true;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                xmlDoc1.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            }



        }
```

Comment: When creating the Treenode you should add the element name  so when you recreate the xml you get the same element names.

Comment: The problem appears in saveNode in first line of foreach loop ( xnode.AppendChild(...) )when I want to continue to put data into xmlDoc1

Comment: You need for the method AppendChild to return the XmlNode : XmlNode child =  xnode.AppendChild().  Then you can add to child.